# Ruby On Rails: How to pass javascript variable to params hash?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a javascript array variable that is created in an `action => new` form but I can't seem to find a way to return this variable as a field to the controller along with the other form field inputs. How do I set this array to a hidden field in the form. Is there a way to pass the array back into the parameters hash to the controller?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    arr = new Array();

        $(document).on('change', 'select[id ^="package"]', function() {
            var arr = $('select[id ^="package"]').map(function(){
                return this.value
            })          
        });

});
```

I have this javascript array and I want to submit the form with `:packages` set to the javascript variable `arr`.

Comment: So you have an array on the client, and want to pass it to the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a hidden field already, you can do this in JavaScript:

```
$('#MODELNAME_packages').val(arr);
```